# python pandas column conditional on two other column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

Is there a way in python pandas to apply a conditional if one or another column have a value?

For one column, I know I can use the following code, to apply a test flag if the column Title includes the word "test".

```
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(df['Title'].str.contains("test|Test"), 'Y', '')
```

But if I would like to say if column title or column subtitle include the word "test", add the test flag, how could I do that?

This obviously didn't work

```
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(df['Title'|'Subtitle'].str.contains("test|Test"), 'Y', '')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pattern = "test|Test"
match = df['Title'].str.contains(pattern) | df['Subtitle'].str.contains(pattern)
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(match, 'Y', '')
```

Answer (score 4):

If many columns then simplier is create subset `df[['Title', 'Subtitle']]` and `apply` [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), because works only with `Series` and check at least one `True` per row by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
mask = df[['Title', 'Subtitle']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("test|Test")).any(axis=1)
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(mask,'Y', '')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['test','Test','e', 'a'], 'Subtitle':['b','a','Test', 'a']})
mask = df[['Title', 'Subtitle']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("test|Test")).any(axis=1)
df['Test_Flag'] = np.where(mask,'Y', '')
print (df)
  Subtitle Title Test_Flag
0        b  test         Y
1        a  Test         Y
2     Test     e         Y
3        a     a
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @jezrael's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Title':['test','Test','e', 'a'],
     'Subtitle':['b','a','Test', 'a']})
```

## `pandas`

you can `stack` + `str.contains` + `unstack`

```
import re

df.stack().str.contains('test', flags=re.IGNORECASE).unstack()

  Subtitle  Title
0    False   True
1    False   True
2     True  False
3    False  False
```

Bring it all together with

```
truth_map = {True: 'Y', False: ''}
truth_flag = df.stack().str.contains(
    'test', flags=re.IGNORECASE).unstack().any(1).map(truth_map)
df.assign(Test_flag=truth_flag)

  Subtitle Title Test_flag
0        b  test         Y
1        a  Test         Y
2     Test     e         Y
3        a     a
```

## `numpy`

*if performance is a concern*

```
v = df.values.astype(str)
low = np.core.defchararray.lower(v)
flg = np.core.defchararray.find(low, 'test') >= 0
ys = np.where(flg.any(1), 'Y', '')
df.assign(Test_flag=ys)

  Subtitle Title Test_flag
0        b  test         Y
1        a  Test         Y
2     Test     e         Y
3        a     a
```

---

***naive time test***

[image]

Comment: @jeangelj, `flag` is "standard" parameter for many functions in the `re` (RegEx) module. So pandas passes this flag further to `re.*` function calls...

Comment: @jeangelj I've updated with another solution for you.