# Python Pandas new column based on value in one column and blank in another

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am cleaning a dataset and want to flag all values, that are incorrectly entered. For example, if a row has category A and a blank subcategory, I want to flag it.

Dataframe df:

```
Category | Subcategory | Value
A              aa         3635
A                         45654
B              bb         3454
C              cc         3674
C                         4575
```

I tried this:

```
df['Format_Flag'] = ' ' 
df['Format_Flag'][(df['Category'] == 'A') & (df['Subcategory'] == ' ')] = 'Y'
```

but it doesn't flag anything.

This is what I get:

```
Category |  Subcategory |   Value  | Format Flag
  A              aa         3635
  A                         45654
  B              bb         3454
  C              cc         3674
  C                         4575
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
Category |  Subcategory |   Value  | Format Flag
  A              aa         3635
  A                         45654        Y
  B              bb         3454
  C              cc         3674
  C                         4575
```

Comment: Use the same approach as in one of your previous question, just change the condition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055206/python-pandas-column-conditional-on-two-other-column-values

Comment: in that question i was looking for two versions of a word in two different columns, not for one word in one column and blank in another; the pattern approach did not work with blank when I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using np.where

```
df['Format_Flag'] = np.where((df['Category'] == 'A') & (df['Subcategory'] == ' '), 'Y', ' N')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df_final['Category'] == 'A') & (df_final['Subcategory'] == ' '),'Format_Flag'] = 'Y'

df = df.fillna('')
```